# Changing animation's 'to' in js doesn't work when emitting an event to trigger the effect

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to play a short rotation animation for this parent camera entity. I have the following a-animation:

```
<a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="1000" to="0 163.5761975835419 0" fill="forwards" begin="rotateCam"></a-animation>
```

Then, I try to set the 'to' attribute *before* emitting rotateCam (with animation.setAttribute(...)), but it only plays the default rotation I set in the HTML. Am I missing something?

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x3yb9cd/) for example. v0.5.0.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and talking to dirkk0 on A-Frame Slack it became clear they're going for a component-based approach. I have changed my code to apply ngokevin's animation component and it solved my problem! :)

[Relevant test (AFrame v0.5.0)](https://jsfiddle.net/3x3yb9cd/1/)

HTML:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" width="1" height="1" depth="1" color="#4CC3D9" animation="property: rotation; dur: 1000; startEvents: rotateBox"></a-box>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>

  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  let box = document.querySelector('a-box');

  box.setAttribute('animation', 'to', '0 20 0');
  box.emit('rotateBox');
}, 2000);
```